How to Change Default .exe Settings
I don't mean just saving a new default startup .blend. I mean how do you make a Blender .exe that has a customized default startup file before it ever even runs the first time?
For example, if I wanted to give someone a Blender .exe to install that never gives them a default cube, how would you do that? I found this:
https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/src/branch/main/scripts/startup/bl_app_templates_system
But I can't find the one for 3D View, the true default. So in my imagination there is a default .blend file somewhere in the source that just gets copied into the OS directory on install.
Hopefully it's not hardcoded and is an actual .blend? ChatGPT is telling me it's hardcoded in C but I don't believe it yet.
I want to do this because my addon is very much not targeted to existing Blender users, so ideally I would be able to provide what's basically a fork that auto installs my addon and sets up my custom .blend startup file. If I have to learn how to build Blender myself, that's fine, but I'm hoping this can be achieved without changing the C.
Because I know I can mess with the built-in python scripts and have it work as expected, so as long as it isn't in the C...

What I've figured out is that I can just put a button on the splash screen .py. And then I think I can just sneak my addon into the default addons folder so it acts like a built-in addon instead of like one you have to manually install. And then I think if I just use that .exe/.app, it will run as expected on a new machine. But I'll obv need a windows version, Apple/Intel version, and a Apple silicone version.

"ChatGPT is telling me..." oh no. Large language models take puzzle pieces of topics and try to shove them together in a way that seems sensical, but it doesn't mean they actually go together. They will readily contradict themselves as they have no information verification system besides patterns of ideas seeming edge-similar to continue the jigsaw puzzle analogy. Never try to use an LLM for research that you do not intend to check yourself afterwards.

@TheLabCat ChatGPT is my part-time developer assistant, and I will readily go to bat to defend its competence any day of the week.

Maybe that's why you're stuck.

I am definitely not stuck, more like on an orbital trajectory.
